# How to proper update table cell info if data was changed in another tab bar controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, refresh

Good day! I really don't know how to ask google for my problem to find good solution. Please help! I have got tab bar controller with T1 and T2 vc. T1 is tableview controller and it shows posts(cells) with like button. So e.g. i look at some post and go to T2 vc. There, i (somehow) navigate to that post and like it. Now if i return back to T1 vc i want that post would be liked. How to do that?

1) I thought about create global array with liked posts and create some update loop in cell to check that array and update data.

2) Or create some delegate methods. But i think it's complex.

If you have some experience in that things, please help. [Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzeiw.jpg)

Comment: each post should have a liked variable. when you like it you toggle it. and in T1 you can check for like posts and update their cells

Comment: You need to start with a model, this will shared between your view controllers, this could be achieved through a singleton (someone hunt me down ;)) or by passing it via the tab bar controller or some other means. The important thing here is that it's shared (you could also use core data or realm or some other data store, which, might make it easier).  Then, when the `viewWillAppear` is called, you can update the view based on the current state of the model

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah! I thought about some singlton;) think answer below is the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most larger apps will solve this by having at least one service that servers as a single source of truth for some kind of shared data.  Each VC then subscribes to this service and updates itself whenever the central store is updated.  Examples of this are using CoreData, Realm, or Firebase (all of which allow you to subscribe to changes in a query).  If you have a simple app you can implement this yourself by posting your own custom `Notification` whenever your data changes.

Comment: Ok, thank you!! I checked it out. These things will solve a lot of my problems!!